# How to capture all clicks from user

Tags: 7, hooks

I need to track all clicks by a user (even with no JavaScript enabled.  What is the best hook_ function to use to track these requests so I may log them?

Comment: You cannot track *all* clicks from a website. If you want to track everywhere a user clicks their mouse on a page, this can be done with Javascript. If you want to track what pages a user views on their journey, you can check out a range of analytic tools that will help you with this (Google Analytics and StatCounter are two examples).

Comment: Hook functions provide a way for experienced developers to modify the behavior of the Drupal Core or any Contributed Modules. For instance, if I have a "bread" module, which allows my users to bake bread, I could add a "hook_put_bread_in_oven()" function to my bread.api.php file.

Then, the "Burnt Bread" module comes along and modifies the "Bread" module to burn all of my bread. In order to do this, it needs to turn the oven up to 500 degrees when I put the bread in.
So burnt_bread_put_bread_in_oven() is written and its body sets oven_temp to 500.

Comment: I know that about JavaScript, hence my "even with no JavaScript enables" comment.  I just need to log user clicks and not modify anything.

Comment: You sound as if you think I didn't read your question fully. The answer to your question exactly how you asked it is simply "you cannot." I was trying to suggest alternatives that might work for you.

Comment: To log a click that doesn't make a server side request, you'll need to use Javascript. Clicks that make a request to the server can be logged server side.

Comment: Thanks David.  I should have worded my question better.  I'm looking for the hook that most menu router requests go through so I can log as many as I can server-side.

Comment: Is hook_url_inbound_alter() the best place to do this for non-javascript page requests?

Comment: Or, it looks like hook_build_page() makes the most sense to me right now.

Comment: check this http://activelamp.com/blog/add-and-track-any-link-google-analytics

Comment: Please edit your question, now it looks like you want to modify browser or something - not exactly on-topic. Explanation about router helps, but in the comment it can be deleted at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Analytics Event Tracking](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et) module to track mouse click and other events. This module provides a hook where you can track click events.

From module page:

> Event Tracking is a way to track user interaction with out registering a page view.
>
> This module allows an interface for Google Analytics event tracking capabilities. It provides a hook for other modules or "glue code" and also has some handy drush commands.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hook_exit() is what I want.  It is called after cached and non-cached page requests, everything is loaded, and cleanup happens.  This seems like the right place to make a logging call.

Comment: and an FYI, hook_exit() has been removed in Drupal 8: https://drupal.org/node/1911186